# Is this how to make an existing JavaScript asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is making JavaScript asynchronous as simple as they make it out to be here? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

For example, if I have this in my HTML:

```
<script src="/whatever.js">
```

And I change it to this:

```
<script src="/whatever.js" async>
```

Does that really make it asynchronous? Is it really that easy?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on what [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) actually does?

Comment: Click on the "Try it yourself" link and you can observe how the alert is shown while the next line in the html source (The "Note: The async attribute..." thing) is parsed and displayed. If you delete the `async` attribute in the script, the next line is displayed only after you click on the "OK" button in the alert box.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `async` attribute does not make your JavaScript code asynchronous. It only indicates to the browser to *load* the script asynchronously.

When you load a JS script without `async`, the parsing of HTML will stop, wait for the script to be downloaded, parsed and executed. After that, it will resume parsing HTML. This guarantees that if you load two scripts: `1.js` and `2.js` in that order, `2.js` will be executed after `1.js`.

When you set `async` attribute on `<script>` tag, it indicates that the script may be loaded asynchronously. In practice, it means that you can’t make assumptions that your code will be executed in the order it was found in the HTML. After the file is downloaded, it will be executed as any other JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to be asynchronous.

That attribute tells the browser to execute the script without waiting for the page to be fully loaded, and in that sense making it asynchronous is that easy.

If, on the other hand, you want the script to execute something (a call to a service maybe) and update the page when the answer comes back, withouth blocking the page while waiting, then you will have to use some [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: I see (and I'm realizing I worded my question poorly, I'm a noob) - yes, I'm wanting to alter existing first and third party JavaScript script tags in the HTML of pages with the async attribute for page speed reasons and prevent render blocking.

The DOCTYPE is XHTML - will adding the async attribute still achieve my intended outcome or does this only work in HTML5?

Thanks for enduring noob grasshopper questions, and thanks so much for the help!